# C# Copy <summary> from other class

Tags: c#, xml

I wanted to declare a new enum/class , but with the exact same `<summary>` from existing class (for programming purpose) , in small scale i can just type the summary manually , but in large scale it takes just too much time copying and pasting , especially with really long `<summary>` . How do i do it ?

For example :

```
/// <summary>
/// Animal
/// </summary>
public enum AnimalListOne {
cat,wolves,fox
}

/// <summary>
/// ..... how do i copy the summary of AnimalListOne ?
/// </summary>
public enum AnimalListTwo {
horse , horseagain , andhorseagain , horsearethebest
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can. You can add a reference, using `<see cref="..."/>`

Comment: There's [inheritdoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc) but it doesn't work for Intellisense, I think. And it would need to there be some inheritance going on, I guess. But you can give it a try. Never really used it.

Comment: @Fildor that's for inheriting from a base class / interface, which isn't happening here. And VS recently got support for `<inheritdoc/>`

Comment: @canton7 Edited my comment accordingly. Just wanted to throw it into the room. It may help OP with other parts of his docs, where inheritance actually is a thing.

Comment: canton7 how do i use it to copy other summary ? sorry i'm beginner at xml and i'm confused when i tried it , and Fildor same question how do i use it to copy summary from other class ?

Comment: Like I said, I don't think you can. No can do. You can add a reference from one type to another using `<see cref="..."/>`

Comment: canton7 the only purpose i write the summary is to make it faster to know what is the class about, i finally understand it thanks but i think it isn't what i was looking for , if it wasn't possible then i guess i will just stick to ctrl + c and ctrl + v manually , thanks for helping canton7 and fildor , at least now i don't need to think about it when i sleep .

Comment: What IDE? If Visual Studio, what version?

Comment: @NetMage currently i uses unity 2018 so it means i use .NET 4.x

Comment: So does that mean you use Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't a built-in way that I can see in VS2019, or even an easy set of keystrokes, but if you add the Visual Commander Extension, you can add a Command to help you. Unfortunately Visual Commander is somewhat buggy, and won't record the macro for you, but you can add it:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class M : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.ExpandSelection");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.SwapAnchor");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineStartExtend");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineStartExtend");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Copy");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.NextMethod");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.NextMethod");
        DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineStart");
    }
}
```

Put the cursor anywhere in a method comment block, and run the macro. It will copy the comment block to the clipboard and move the cursor to the beginning of the following method. Then you can either paste, or click to put the cursor at the beginning of another method and paste.

Comment: wow thank you ! you actually spent time to make the workaround, not the answer to the problem , but hey this works ! thanks again .